# Existence of one to one,onto function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A=\{x^2:0\lt x\lt1\} $and $B=x^3:1\lt x\lt2 \}$.Then which of the following statement is true?
1.There is a one to one ,onto function from A to B.
2.There is no one to one ,onto function from A to B taking rationals to irrationals.
3.There is no one to one ,onto function from A to B which is onto.
4.There is no onto function from A to B which is one to one.

Comment: any thoughts about the question?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? (Also, I hope there's a typo in (3): "no one to one, onto function which is onto"?)

Comment: I don't undertand how to start and there is no error in option 3.

Comment: Isn't it just asking about maps from $(0,1)$ to $(1,8)$? Why need the $x^2$, $x^3$ stuffs?

Comment: @velutluna Probably to test the learner's capability to figure that part out by themselves.

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE Then question 3 is horribly redundant. It could just ask to prove or disprove if there is a one to one, onto function from A to B, unless there's something I'm misunderstanding. EDIT: Actually, for that matter, questions 3 and 4 are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. Simplify what are the sets $A$ and $B$ might help.
2. Think about countability.

Comment: +1 For a hint rather than an answer. OP should be able to see that the question is fairly simple after simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

$A = (0,1)$ and $B = (1,8)$. It is simple to construct a bijection between these.

One example is the following linear function: Define $f : A \to B$ by

$$f(x) = 7x + 1$$

and you have your bijection.

Comment: I got it.Thanks.